# Textbox center in css

Tags: css, html, devextreme

I can successfully center textbox in CSS. But the centered Textboxes are not aligned. How do I align them?

My html code:

```
  <div data-bind="dxList: { dataSource: dataSource}">
    <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } ">

        <div class="wrapper">
               <div data-bind="text: name" class="cls"></div>
            <input name="deneme" id="test" type="text"  />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks somewhat like this right now

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Notes:** Using `margin: 0 auto` then horizontal align center element or Div

**Method-1: Using** `display: flex;`.

```css
#test,
.test {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div data-bind="text: name" class="cls"></div>
  <input name="deneme" id="test" type="text" />
</div>
```

**Method-2: Using** `display: block;`

```css
#test,
.test {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div data-bind="text: name" class="cls"></div>
  <input name="deneme" id="test" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it not working. The centered Textboxes are not aligned.

Comment: textbox center  as expcted your questions. what do you want plz briefly  your questions

Comment: Not all textboxes are aligned. They are just in the middle. You can see the example above.

Comment: ok. you want to first textbox center after second or other some left side previous textbox right ??

Comment: Yes, can you help me pls?

Comment: see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/3z6yzf76 check it . any issue or query then put on comment

Answer (score 0):

try with this css :

```
input {
   width:100px;
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-
To center a div with `margin: 0 auto;` like suggested the div must contain a valid width.

If you add

```
#register{
 //...
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center your div in the center horizontally. You can also use `text-align:` center in the parent with `display: inline-block` in the form div. Such as:

```
#fg_membersite{
 text-align:center;
}

#register{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want to center it also in the vertical i suggest you use `display:table` (on the aprent div) and `display:table-cell` (in a wrapper div) and `vertical-align:middle` options , or maybe a `position:absolute` with negative margins, it's your choice.